# How to Use LINE Notify for send multiple images

Tags: curl

I have a code send notify to line.
but this code can't send multiple images from my computer.
This code sent 1 word & 1 Pic.

```
curl -X POST https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify -H "Authorization: Bearer my_token" -F "message=Basic service verification" -F "imageFile=@C:/Users/Oliver/Pictures/PIC/test.jpg"
```

I try it. But not work.

```
curl -X POST https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify -H "Authorization: Bearer my_token" -F "message=Basic service verification" -F "imageFile=@C:/Users/Oliver/Pictures/PIC/test.jpg" -F "imageFile=@C:/Users/Oliver/Pictures/PIC/test2.jpg" -F "imageFile=@C:/Users/Oliver/Pictures/PIC/test3.jpg"
```

Comment: What is the error that you get when running the second command?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation I was able to find [here](https://notify-bot.line.me/doc/en/), I don't think multiple image parameters are possible. You might have to resort to sending multiple POST's.